# Using JRE 11 with Vert.x in docker

Tags: java, docker, vert.x

I've been trying to setup a simple vert.x application in docker and have followed this guide on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/vertx/vertx3) and created a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM vertx/vertx3

#                                                       (1)
ENV VERTICLE_NAME com.X.Y.MainVerticle
ENV VERTICLE_FILE target/application-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar

# Set the location of the verticles
ENV VERTICLE_HOME /usr/verticles

EXPOSE 8888

# Copy your verticle to the container                   (2)
COPY $VERTICLE_FILE $VERTICLE_HOME/


# Launch the verticle
WORKDIR $VERTICLE_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["exec vertx run $VERTICLE_NAME -cp $VERTICLE_HOME/*"]
```

But I have a problem because the MainVerticle class is compiled with Java 11 but vertx/vertx3 is using JRE8 so this generates:

```
 Failed to deploy verticle com.X.Y.MainVerticle 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/X/Y/MainVerticle has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:37)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.createVerticles(DeploymentManager.java:243)
```

One alternative that I understand it would be to compile the class with Java 8, but then it complains about not finding the Future class:

```
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer.listen(I)Lio/vertx/core/Future;
        at com.X.Y.MainVerticle.start(MainVerticle.java:35)
```

So then I tried upping the JRE in the docker container, which I can't quite figure out how to do. You can't modify it with `VERTX_OPTIONS`, so that is a no go. What seems like it could work is that you add `FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot` in the Dockerfile, but that creates another container that don't know what vertx is. I'm at a loss here, I'm probably missing something basic here because it feels like there should be an easy way to control your JRE version in a docker container.

How can I solve this so I can run my simple Vert.x application in docker?

Comment: These docker images will go away in the next version of Vert.x. I would recommend creating your image as explained in https://how-to.vertx.io/executable-jar-docker-howto/

Comment: Thanks a lot, following that guide I was able to start it properly!